# Single word for jumping for joy

Tags: single-word-requests

I know that I can say "I jumped for joy yesterday along with her." But I want it to be more concise than that while replacing a single verb, as in:

> - I _____ yesterday along with her.
>
> [image: picture for jumping for joy]

Comment: I think “jumping for joy” is a set phrase because there is no single word for that action in English.

Comment: @Dan: I think not! :)

Comment: ...I was kinda hoping someone might have been creative enough to "verbify" ***Snoopy*** (as when Snoopy [ecstatically spins his ears like ***this*** while jumping up and down](http://corecontrarian.blogspot.com/2011/12/prince-is-just-ecstatic-today-for-some.html)), but apparently some killjoy linguist says [we can't verbify that specific noun](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=6lZiAAAAMAAJ&q=%22snoopied%22&dq=%22snoopied%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5gK7T243dAhUFGuwKHbueDaYQ6AEILjAB) (he's marked ***he snoopied*** with an asterisk, meaning "not an acceptable utterance").

Comment: If you allow ad memes, *Toyota*. :P

Answer (score 9):

The exact word you are looking for is **Exultant**. It literally means ***jumping out of your skin with joy***.

Exultant [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/exult)

> *Meaning:* to be extremely joyful : rejoice
>
> *Usage:* the team exulted in their victory

*obsolete : **to leap for joy***

Verb: Exult

`I` ***exulted*** `yesterday along with her.`

Edit:

The word **exult** is made up of **ex** + **sult**. The prefix **ex** mean ***out of*** and suffix **sult** means ***jump*** . So, etymologically, it means *jump out of oneself with joy*.

Comment: Please explain why it is not correct.

Comment: Same as here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/461975/single-word-for-jumping-for-joy/461976?noredirect=1#comment1114295_461976

Comment: You might want to give the verb form in order to fit the sentence...?

Comment: I think this is quite a good one, actually. Especially on account of the etymology (which without checking, I assume is the same as French ***sauter = to jump***, and English ***somersault***).

Comment: ...But rightly or wrongly I associate the verb ***to exult*** more with ***gloating*** (often, being gleeful about an enemy's failure), rather that true rejoicing with no connotations of this being occasioned by the failure of evil to triumph.

Comment: @Hellion ok! did necessary changes :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks :) I edited the answer with verb form

Comment: @DanBron sorry! but etymologically it means -- jumping out of the skin. So, I think it is perfect fit.

Comment: @ubihatt Except it does not convey to your listener the physical act of jumping. No one will understand you to mean that if you use this word, regardless of etymology. The answer does not answer the question. It would be a better answer if you said “there is no word so far as I know which means ‘jumping for joy’, but you can convey at least the emotional state with this word. It’s different to why you asked for, but it may be useful anyway.’

Comment: I must at least ask you to provide a source for the assertion that "exultant" means "jumping out of your skin with joy." That isn't a definition I'm familiar with, nor is it supported by the link you provided.

Comment: @KamilDrakari exult is made up of **ex** +  **sult**. The prefix  **ex** mean ***out*** ***of*** and suffix **sult** means  ***jump*** . So, etymologically, it means jump out of oneself with joy.

Comment: The OED does support a "leaping" definition, but lists it as ***obsolete*** (last citation is from 1727). So *exult* isn't going to be associated with the OP's imagery for modern hearers, though it makes an interesting bit of trivia.

Comment: @ubihatt etymology and meaning are distinct, and the question is tagged with "single-word-request" not "etymology". "Exult" is not a good verb if you wish to communicate in English that a person was jumping for joy, and in the sample sentence OP provided it would not be interpreted the way they wish.

Comment: @ubihatt, the verb **exult** has become obsolete when it is meant to leap to for joy. Can I use this verb in modern English?

Comment: @ubihatt, The obsolescence of **exult** led me to unaccept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

Possibly "gambol" (pronounced as gamble)

> intr.v.
>   To leap about playfully; frolic.
>  n.
>  A playful
>   skipping or frolicking about.
>  [American Heritage
>   Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/gambol)
>
> verb
>  [no object usually with adverbial]
>  Run or jump about
>   playfully. ‘the mare gambolled towards her’ 
>   noun
>  An act of running or
>   jumping about playfully. 'the two of them run off to the woods for a
>   gambol together’ 
> [Oxford Living Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/gambol)

Some synonyms for gambol are frolic, romp, play, but none of these as far as I know have the meaning of to jump playfully. However "caper" and "prance" are similar to "gambol"

Whether playfully can mean happily, I'm not sure, but "playfully" seems to suggest happiness or joy to me.

I'm also not sure whether "a gambol" can refer to a single jump, or whether it has to mean a continued act of playful jumping.

I did a search for "gambol" to mean a single jump and came up with a few results, though these are by no means strong support.

> A gambol (n.) is the energetic leap of a horse. It is also an outburst
>   of energetic and playful activity—not necessarily involving a horse—or
>   a general frolic or romp.
>  [Gambol and Gimbal blog](http://verbmall.blogspot.com/2015/01/gimbol-and-gimbal.html)

> He thrust at me, but I leapt over his spear thus,” and he gambolled
>   into the air.
>  [Children of the Storm](https://www.gutenberg.org/files/1711/1711-h/1711-h.htm) A book published in 2012
>   (This does not suggest happiness, as it's describing a fight.)

> Etymology of "gambol": In Middle French, the noun "gambade" referred to the frisky spring of
>   a jumping horse.
>  [Merriam Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/gambol)

[thesaurus.com](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/gambol) lists "leap" and "spring" as synonyms.

Comment: Isn't jumping **with joy** and jumping **playfully** means two different things?

Comment: @ubihatt Yes, they are. That's why I had reservations about posting this answer. As the OP posted pictures of people jumping I thought they wanted a word to literally mean "to jump". This word was the closest I could come up with to match that. I'm now doubting the OP actually requires this literal meaning of jumping. If this is the case I'll delete my answer.

Answer (score 2):

> [***rejoice***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/rejoice)
>   *- to feel or show great happiness about something*

Note that ***jump for joy*** is in [this list of synonyms](https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/rejoice?s=t) for ***rejoice*** at *thesaurus.com.*

---

A bit further off the beaten track, there's also...

> [***ecstasize***](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ecstasize)
>    *- to go into an ecstasy*

Comment: Sorry, had to -1. Neither one of these contains or describes the physical act of jumping.

Comment: Hmm. I'd guess the vast majority of instances of ***jumping for joy*** don't actually involve lifting both feet off the ground simultaneously. Regardless of OP's pretty pictures, it's generally a ***figurative*** usage. Whatever - I rest my case on the fact that ***rejoice*** and ***jump for joy*** both appear on the same "synonyms" page, as previously noted.

Comment: His pictures show literal jumps, and it's clear (at least in my reading), OP is looking for that actual physical action. Not abstract celebration. Literal jumping for joy.

Comment: Perhaps I should have had the courage of my (creative) convictions, and proposed the verbified version of propeller-eared Snoopy in his "ultra-happy place"!

Comment: +1 I agree that the phrase *jumping for joy* is almost never meant literally. (While the question shows pictures of people jumping, I don't think it's a good interpretation of the phrase.) Therefore, this is an excellent single-word alternative to the metaphorical expression.

Answer (score 2):

The verb you are looking for is *cavorted*, from the root form *cavort*.

Definition of *cavort* (from [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cavort)):

> **cavorted; cavorting; cavorts**
>   *intransitive verb*
>   **1 :** to leap or dance about in a lively manner | Otters *cavorted* in the stream.

Comment: Please include a source and a link to it (if a web-based source) for your definition.

Comment: I would be wary of the word *cavort* in this context; as a native speaker I would understan that as having connotation of the second of Merriam-Webster's definitions: "to spend time in an enjoyable and often wild or improper way". Particularly if you are a man, *I cavorted with her yesterday* will be readily interpreted as sexual.

Comment: Indeed, that is the alternate, but now more commonly accepted, definition. May partially explain why the word has fallen out of use.

Answer (score -3):

Sounds like you're ecstatic.

Need more characters to post, hmm.
Ecstatic: a state of ecstasy. I think. Sounds right.

Comment: You might have a decent enough suggestion there. Not my votes, but you're probably getting downvotes because you haven't included anything that isn't just opinion. If you look at the other answers, you'll see that they all contain block quotes of dictionary references. [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com) is a good start. It'll use up characters(!) and you'll be able to back up opinion with accepted references (which is good for upvotes). You can edit your answer if you like, too. I find it sad when people downvote and leave no reasons behind.